# RHEL5 Qt compiler/linker/qmake issues... advice?

Tags: linux, qt, compiler-construction, redhat

I have about a few problems with a new install of the Qt SDK. I probably only need advice, but specific answers are also welcome. Before I begin a mini-story, I am running RHEL5 on academic license under VirtualBox on OSX 10.6. Using Qt version 4.5.3. This is my situation...

1.) I couldn't compile because g++ wasn't found. I fixed this by creating a link: g++ -> g++34. This allowed me to compile but it generated more errors at link-time. I had installed the framework in my home directory unintentionally so I uninstalled/reinstalled the entire SDK to /usr/local/qt.

2.) At this point I could compile but the linker complained about a missing freetype package. I had that already installed but wasn't sure why it couldn't be found. So I installed a few packages that I thought might be missing like libqt4-devel and libqt4-devel-debug. I also installed a few other general programming packages for later use.

3.) Somehwere in this process I can no longer run qmake. I ran it before and I have it installed at /usr/local/qt/qt/bin/qmake. I could create a link to it (though I shouldn't have to OR I could ensure that the location was in the PATH var). However, at this point Qt Creator says there's no Qt installation found. I re-pointed it to the installation location (using Tools/Options) but it still won't run qmake or anything else for that matter...

I only need this linux install to compile and test my Qt projects which I am developing in OSX. So my question is, should I just wipe this RHEL install and start over? And if so, should I use something else like Ubuntu? I am having plenty of hassles that I don't want to deal with as is. Note, this project will require good OpenGL support.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason that you don't simply use the Qt package that's part of RHEL?

If for some reason you need to build your own, you can get all of the build dependancies with:

```
$ yum install yum-utils
$ yum-builddep <whatever the qt package's name is>
```

Comment: The qt package on Fedora is `qt`.  The development package is `qt-devel`.  RHEL *probably* uses the same package names.

Answer (score 0):

@scotchi is right, and you should try to use the Qt package that comes with your system unless you need a very different version.  I don't know what version of Qt comes with RHEL but if its not up-to-date enough for you (and it might not be, see below) then you could consider changing OS versions.  I would only do this after trying his suggestion though, because you may be able to get things working without the hassle of a full OS install.

Now, as to why you might want to switch: RHEL is, as its name ("Enterprise Linux") indicates aimed at companies who want to run servers, or large deployments of desktops.  It emphasizes stability and reliability over being cutting edge.  Fairly often the version of the compiler and development libraries lag a little behind the curve.  This is what their clients want: a stable platform they can develop against and run programs on for a period of time, not constantly needing to keep up with the latest changes, and thoroughly tested.  But for people doing development at home it may not be necessary to stay that conservative.  I don't know if this is for work, school or personal programming, but it sounds to me like you should move to one of the more desktop-oriented distros.  Ubuntu is great, as is Fedora.  If you prefer a RHEL-like environment, then choose Fedora.